# What is the context of the quote "With great power comes great responsibility"?

Tags: comics, spider-man, quotes, marvel

Without a doubt, this is one of the most famous quotes from Spider-Man. I think that in the movie, it's Uncle Ben who says it.

However, was the quote also present in the comics? More importantly, what was the context of the quote, since AFAIK Uncle Ben and Peter Parker were not in positions of power at the time?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I can't find the comic number itself, but here is the only instance of it that I know of in the actual comics. It was not said to Peter by anyone, just a caption box.

[image: Two panels from a Spider-Man comic are shown. In the first panel the narration begins "And, a short distance away..." Peter, in Spider-Man costume but with his mask off, holds his forehead in his right hand as he weeps. "My fault--all my fault! If only I had stopped him when I could have! But I didn't--and now--Uncle Ben--is dead..." In the second panel the narration continues "And a lean, silent figure slowly fades into the gathering darkness, aware at last that in this world, with great power there much also come--great responsibility!" Peter is seen as a small figure, head bowed, walking away down an empty street edged by tall buildings, with a full moon in the sky above him. The narration concludes "And so a legend is born and a new name is added to the roster of those who make the world of fantasy the most exciting realm of all!"]

Information found [here](https://goodcomics.comicbookresources.com/2006/12/07/comic-book-urban-legends-revealed-80/)

Comment: Nice answer. I would also like to point out that the quote is not used in the exact form here, so later editions change that as well.

Comment: *AMAZING FANTASY* #15, Spider-Man's first appearance.

Answer (score 33):

From the [wikipedia page of Ben Parker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncle_Ben):

> The often-quoted Spider-Man theme of
> "with great power comes great
> responsibility" is widely attributed
> to Uncle Ben. However, this was not
> initially true. In Amazing Fantasy
> No.15, the original version of the phrase appears in a narrative caption
> in the comic's last panel,[11] not as
> spoken dialogue. In fact, Ben has only
> two lines in the entire comic.
>
> However, later stories and flashbacks
> that took place when Ben was still
> alive retroactively made the phrase
> one of Ben's many homilies he would
> lecture Peter with. Latter-day
> reinterpretations of Spider-Man, such
> as the Spider-Man movie and the
> Ultimate Spider-Man comic, depict Ben
> as saying this phrase to Peter while
> he is still alive, in their last
> conversation. Both the aforementioned
> adaptations also had Peter lash out at
> Ben just after he says it, and both
> also mention his father. Also, in
> Marvel: Ultimate Alliance, when the
> player speaks with Spider-Man, they
> attempt to say the phrase to him, only
> for him to interrupt them.
>
> We can attribute the earliest usage of
> this phrase to Voltaire, albeit in
> French[12].
>
> New York City Mayor-Elect Thomas
> Francis Gilroy used the phrase "With
> great power comes great
> responsibility" in an 1892 interview
> with The New York Times.[13][14]

Comment: I know this is old, but the Voltaire attribution may be in error: https://quoteinvestigator.com/2015/07/23/great-power/ (Unless Voltaire was part of the FNC :p)

Answer (score 3):

It's used in several contexts.

In the saturday morning cartoons, it was a common voice over and editorial comment by Stan Lee, and also in internal monologues by Peter Parker. In Amazing Fantasy #15, it's also a narrative context.

It's attributed in later canon to Uncle Ben, both shown as Ben speaking it to Peter in the car, and also Peter in narrator mode (especially in the cartoons) mentioning it in internal monologue, usually in the form of, "As Uncle Ben said, 'With great power comes great responsibility.'"

It has also been used on occasion by other characters; I don't remember exactly where, but ISTR Professor X has used it as an occasional admonition to students at the Xavier School.